# Cross-domain $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

UPDATE
For now I've received nothing except for tuning **working code**.
What is wrong with this logic?
I make a $.ajax call with dataType:'jsonp', cause it's the only way for cross-domain calls.
I know, that call expects 'jsonp' type, but instead receives 'text/html'. How can I parse this responce (convert, pre-process, filter)?

Thank you!

Here is a question. 
I'm just trying to get the idea of using jSON. 
Here is a that works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li a').click(function (){
    var test = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="www.mohtasebi.com/blog/2011/06/cross-domain-ajax-using-jquery-the-ultimate-guide/"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
  //var test = "http://mohtasebi.com/blog/2011/06/cross-domain-ajax-using-jquery-the-ultimate-guide/";
    loadPage(test);
    });
});

function loadPage(test)
{
    $.ajax({
    url:test,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    crossDomain: 'true',
    success: function(data){    
    if ( data.results[0] ) {     
    alert("ok")
    } }
});

}
```

**But if I use commented url**

> var test =
>   "http://mohtasebi.com/blog/2011/06/cross-domain-ajax-using-jquery-the-ultimate-guide/";

**instead of [YUI converted](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) I get this error:**

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html:
>   "http://mohtasebi.com/blog/2011/06/cross-domain-ajax-using-jquery-the-ultimate-guide/?callback=jQuery18104882542605046183_1347794498881&_=1347794500464".
>   jquery.min.js:8169 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   mohtasebi.com:1

What I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.getJSON`, which is much simpler.

```
var test = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="www.mohtasebi.com/blog/2011/06/cross-domain-ajax-using-jquery-the-ultimate-guide/"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
$.getJSON(test, function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TWmqk/)***

​

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is with commented url, not coverted using YUI.

Comment: @Dmitry That url doesn't return jsonp response, what do you want ?

Comment: Yes, and my question is what can I do about it?

Comment: @Dmitry Because the response is not valid javascript, how could you use execute html as javascript?

Comment: Using this code http://jsfiddle.net/reeFj/, browser gets mohtasebi.com
mohtasebi.com/blog/2011/06/cross-domain-ajax-using-jquery-the-ultimate-guide
GET
200
OK
text/html
jquery.min.js:8169
Script
18.41KB
18.12KB
2.10s
529ms. Is it possible to parse this data?

Comment: Just to clearify. What's response type of data. Can I convert it to a valid javascript?

Comment: @Dmitry First the content should be valid javascript.

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="www.mohtasebi.com/blog/2011/06/cross-domain-ajax-using-jquery-the-ultimate-guide/"') + '&format=xml';

$.ajax({
    url: test,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'blah',  // just add this and remove &callback=? from url last
    crossDomain: 'true',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);  // see the console for data
        if (data.results[0]) {
            alert('OK');
        }
    }
});​
```

Add `jsonpCallback` to ajax config and remove &callback=? from url last part.

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TWmqk/4/)***